# Select a particular type of columns that begin with a certain letter and fetch data all together

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch data at the same time I select specific type of columns
what I`m doing is:

```
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'table'
        AND table_schema = 'DB'
        AND column_name LIKE 'f%'
```

this query will give  me the col names, there is option to fetch data of those colum at the same time? or I need to take the array of the cols and make another query? let say I want to fetch all the data, it doesnt matter.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a stored procedure for this, with dynamic sql.

first, you must create this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FetchColumns (IN pSchemaName char(50), IN pTableName char(50), IN     pColumnLikeCondition char(50))
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_cols char(200);
  SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME separator ' , ') INTO v_cols FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = pTableName
       AND table_schema = pSchemaName
       AND column_name LIKE pColumnLikeCondition;

  SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ',v_cols,' FROM ',pTableName );
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

and finally, all you have to do is calling it, like this:

```
call FetchColumns('DB', 'table', 'f%')
```

Comment: What do you want exactly to do? Just call this SP from PHP, or also create it!

Comment: I want to make a query that will give me the data of those cols, there is option like that? OR I need to make  the first query to get the cols names than take this array and fetch data of those cols for each col?

Comment: You can:
- either create the "FetchColumns" SP and then call it from PHP, it returns all data for the wanted cols.
- or make a first query to get all columns names, then build a second query with these names to get data

Comment: OK thanks, I tried to run this query in the sql console ( in the phpmyadmin ) and there is no result. maybe I did something wrong. any way thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Ok what if you

- first get the column name as you are doing right now
- then use the column names in another query using php or something to get your data

because i dont think there's another direct way of doing it.