# SELECT array of cols FROM table

Tags: php, mysql

I`m trying to select array of fields from table, the problem that its about 200 cols.
I wonder what is the best way to do that, in my last post I wanted to select specific type of cols that start with a letter ( you can see it here [select a particular type of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961849/select-a-particular-type-of-columns-that-begin-with-a-certain-letter-and-fetch-d))
so what I did is:

```
include '../connect.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tel_Aviv');
$datestamp = date("mY");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'd".$datestamp."'
        AND table_schema = '".$db."'
        AND column_name LIKE '%f%'");

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $result_array[] = implode($r);

}
print_r($result_array); // see the cols result.

$Data = mysql_query("SELECT ".($result_array)." FROM d".$datestamp." LIMIT 0,1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Data)){
    echo implode($row);
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: 200 column ..... without normalization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result_array = array(); // intialize the result array
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        // add the column name to the array
        $result_array[] = '`' . $r['COLUMN_NAME'] . '`';

}
print_r($result_array); // see the cols result.

$Data = mysql_query("SELECT ".implode(', ', $result_array)." FROM d".$datestamp." LIMIT 0,1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Data)){
    echo implode($row);
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: result_array ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> SHOW COLUMNS FROM mydb.mytable;

More info in the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

you can to do it like this..

```
$string = implode(",", $result_array);

$Data = mysql_query("Select $string From d".$datestamp." LIMIT 0,1");
```